# Expression of trigonometric function

Tags: simplifying-expressions, trigonometry

I have a complicate expression with a lot of trigonometric functions. And I want to express the function just in the form of $\cos(\theta)$ and $\sin(\theta)$ instead of something like $\cos(2\theta)$ or $\cos(\theta/2)$. What should I to achieve this? Thanks!

For example, if I want to express the following expression in

```
Cos[theta1/2]^2* ( Cos[theta3/2]^4 +Sin[theta3/2]^4 + c* Sin[theta3]^2)
```

in $\cos(\theta_1)$ and $\cos(\theta_3)$ and $\sin(\theta_3)$, are there any functions that can do this change.

Comment: Without a minimal example, it is a bit difficult to offer any help. Please load copy-paste-able Mathematica code. Thanks.

Comment: @Syed I have updated the question

Comment: `Cos[θ1/     2]^2 (Cos[θ3/2]^4 + Sin[θ3/2]^4 +       c Sin[θ3]^2) // TrigReduce // Map[TrigExpand]` ? Sorry about deleting my comment when I realized it had those terms. Try this one.

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot!